# NameError: name 'Base' is not defined

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Following is my file having all Table mapper classes.

```
// import statements
Class MyBase(AbstractBase, Base):
    session = None
    def __init__(self):
        global Session
        self.session = Session()
        // init statements

Class Table1(MyBase):
    // fields

engine = create_engine("...")

Session = session_maker(engine)

Base = declarative_base()

Base.meta.create_all()
```

1. I am getting `NameError: name 'Base' is not defined` since my class is extending it before `Base` initialization.
2. I can make it work, if I move engine creation, Session creation & Base creation above defining classes. But `Base.meta.create_all()` should be present below the class declaration. If I place `Base.meta.create_all()` above classes, there is no table created.
3. I do not want to have the `main()` because, I am basically going to import this file in some other file.

So, I want to keep all statements(engine, session, base & create_all()) after the class definitions.

**EDIT:**

I moved engine, Session, Base to base.py & importing it to define Tables in tables.py. & imported both in test.py. test.py will call create_tables() which is defined as static method in base.py.

Comment: You can't. You cannot create the models without the `Base` class. Move those lines to a separate module and import that separate module if you want to separate the lines, but you cannot, fundamentally, do what you are asking for.

Comment: Is there any way to do like this class `MyBase(AbstractBase, globals.Base)`?

Comment: No, because you haven't yet defined `Base`.

Comment: So, I can move engine, session etc except Base.meta.create_all() to another module?

Comment: Yes. And I'd move `Base.meta.create_all()` to a utility function; I'd not *always* want to execute that line.

Comment: I edited the question. is it right approach?

Comment: Yes, that looks fine.